# Spring @JsonView how can use request parameter or header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

[@JsonView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoLsU.jpg)

how can use like parameter from request:

```
@JsonView(header="range")
```

when response value,read request header `range` to exclude/include some field

Comment: you can implement custom `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring  this is @JsonView on method, I want to change it read from parameter or header,according to the parameters dynamically generated json

Comment: yeeees. But this will not add you a possibility to dynamically add/remove fields to be serialized.  Thus in order to proceed with this you have to implement 2 custom request methods: like "/list/with_range" and  "/list"

Comment: no,2 method not good，where is @JsonView resolve?could i change resolve to read from header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonView provides "static" view mapping. so for your dynamic behaviour you can do like this:

```
// actual request handling is happened here
private ResponseEntity<SomeObject> processRequest();

// request handling with view limit in result
@JsonView(YourDefinedView.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", headers={"range=include"}) 
public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> processWithView() {
    return processRequest();
}


// request handling without view (no headers specified) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/request")
public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> processWithoutView() {
    return processRequest();
}
```

this will map your client to same request url, but depending on header it will provide view or not. Than you can create a set of methods, that will be using different `@JsonView` depending on headers information.

But with this you will limit only the data transfered to client, and the whole data load will happen on server. For example with database and JPA, if you would like not to fetch from database all that data you will end with `javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraphs`, which will change the general logic of your application - and will at the end of the day produce 2 different methods.

And if you would like to expose custom header with list of fields, to be serialized - custom DTO object, or `Map<String, Object>` (ugly-ugly-ugly) or custom `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` comes to your help.